# Annotate bars without showing 0 values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, countplot

[image: Seaborn Image]

I do not want to see the 0s being displayed in the countplot. Is there a way to eliminate showing just 0s from the labels on the graph?

```
ax = sbn.countplot(data=df,x='link',hue='Status', width=0.2)

for container in ax.containers:
  ax.bar_label(container,)
```

Comment: is "filtering your data so you don't even _have_ zeroes to show" an option?

Comment: `ax.bar_label(container, fmt=lambda x: x if x > 0 else '')` with matplotlib 3.7.1, or `labels = [v.get_height() if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v in c]` and `ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center')`

Comment: Thank you Trenton. The following code worked.  ax.bar_label(container, fmt=lambda x: x if x > 0 else '')